# Dont understand this syntax

Tags: c, syntax

Given this loop, why is there a semi colon at the end?

```
for(s = string; *s == ' '; s++)
    ;
```

thanks

edit * so is it possible to reverse this procedure so it starts at the end of a string and checks for a space and decreases until it finds a charachter?

Comment: change it to use ++s -- it has the potential to produce better code.

Comment: Why would that make the code better? It would be the exact same thing in this example.

Comment: That would be the case if you have a compiler that has the correct optimization (which most do, hence the word "potential"). It is good practise to use pre-incrememnt unless post-increment is required -- the optimization isn't generally applied to non-built-in types.

Comment: To answer your edit, yes, it's possible: `size_t len = strlen(string); char *s; for (s=string+len; *s == ' '; --s) ;`

Answer (score 6):

It is an empty statement, which is a no-op in C. It's as if you had said:

```
for(s = string; *s == ' '; s++)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

You use this when everything can be done in the `for( ... )` construct itself - the C grammar requires that there be a controlled statement, but there is nothing for it to do.

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't been accepted as the answer after 6 years

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon means that nothing is done inside the loop. In your code the loop just loops until the character in the string is not a space. That is, after that line s points to the first character in the string that is not a space.

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon makes an empty statement in the loop. This loop searches for the first non-blank `char` in `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C (and others) for grammar is:
for (init; condition; step) 
   body

Where body can be a closure ( a block of code in {}), but body can also be a empty with ;

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that the loop could be written like this to make it more explicit what is going on and increase readability:

```
 for(s = string; *s == ' ';)
     s++;
```

Or using a while loop:

```
 s = string;
 while(*s == ' ')
     s++;
```

But I think the first approach with the empty body is more "c-idiomatic" (and harder to read).

Comment: The increase in readability is in your eyes only, IMHO. The fact that the original form is idiomatic is what makes it easy for experienced C programmers to read.

Comment: well, the *only* reason we are talking about it is because the OP had problem understanding it...

Answer (score 0):

It causes the loop to do nothing. All that happens is that the pointer is advanced.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a statement or block as the "body" of the `for` loop.  This is what is executed each time through the loop (as long as `s` is still pointing to a space).

A semicolon on its own is the *empty* statement -- that is, nothing happens in the loop body, just the `s++` on the `for` loop line.